# vim bind to update initialization without restarting. How to add the loading of local .vimrc?

Tags: vimscript, startup

Here's my existing bind I'm looking to improve:

```
nnoremap <Leader>L :so $MYVIMRC<CR>:runtime! after/plugin/*.vim<CR>:runtime! after/ftplugin/*.vim<CR>
```

This doesn't work to source `<cwd>/.vimrc`.

How do I add that (probably just `:so .vimrc`), and more importantly, what is the order in which that actually gets sourced on startup, so I can replicate that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're suggesting that `<cwd>/.vimrc` gets loaded automatically. It *usually* doesn't (exceptions noted below). Only one `.vimrc` file gets loaded and that's normally going to be `$HOME/.vimrc`. You'll know which one gets picked up because that's what you see in `$MYVIMRC`. In other words `$MYVIMRC` is normally set once the `.vimrc` location has been determined as opposed to `$MYVIMRC` dictating what Vim will load.

There are a couple ways to subvert this:

- As noted in [Mass's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/vim-bind-to-update-initialization-without-restarting-how-to-add-the-loading-of#comment23294_13595) there actually is an option to read `.vimrc` from the current directory! Read `:h 'exrc'`, though, as it *strongly* discourages use of this option for security reasons (though if you set `'secure'` as well it's apparently less dangerous).
- If you are so inclined you can pre-set `$MYVIMRC` in which case the standard vimrc location rules don't apply. See `:h .vimrc` for a complete description of all of this.

In any case, if you want to load `.vimrc` from your working directory in your mapping then you're right that you simply add `:so .vimrc`.

FYI there are two ways to see what has been loaded and in what order:

- Start Vim with this flag `-V2<outfile>`. In *outfile* you will see some verbose output that includes all sourced files.
- If Vim is already running do `:scriptnames` to display sourced files.

Comment: It is plausible (though highly ill-advised) that OP has "set exrc," in which case `./.vimrc` would be sourced.

Comment: Yes you're right! I have `set exrc` and `set secure` in my vimrc. I had forgotten that i use this.

Comment: I am going to try to eliminate this. mainly i just need project specific vimrcs to configure ALE.

Comment: Wow. I thought @Mass was going out on a limb with his theory given how vehemently `:help 'exrc'` warns against using it. Never say never, eh? For accuracy's sake I'd like to mention this in my answer, crediting you, but don't want to be seen as trying to steal rep....if you write an answer I'll link to it from mine.